# MySql Ordering by specific field value first does not work

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

Hello I have a news page, I want to show the user's city news at the top. 
For example these are the news ordered descending by time.

```
+----------+-----------+-----------------------+
| CityCode | entrytime |      newsheader       |
+----------+-----------+-----------------------+
|       11 |      3800 | great opening         |
|       10 |      3700 | flood alert           |
|       12 |      3600 | new mall              |
|       13 |      3500 | pollution at the city |
|       13 |      3400 | new mayor             |
|       12 |      3300 | house fire            |
|       11 |      3200 | traffic accident      |
|       10 |      3000 | Festival at city      |
+----------+-----------+-----------------------+
```

I live in the city 12. I want to see CityCode=12 at the top, then other news like this.

```
+----------+-----------+-----------------------+
| CityCode | entrytime |      newsheader       |
+----------+-----------+-----------------------+
|       12 |      3600 | new mall              |
|       12 |      3300 | house fire            |
|       11 |      3800 | great opening         |
|       10 |      3700 | flood alert           |
|       13 |      3500 | pollution at the city |
|       13 |      3400 | new mayor             |
|       11 |      3200 | traffic accident      |
|       10 |      3000 | Festival at city      |
+----------+-----------+-----------------------+
```

I tried

```
Select * from news order by FIELD(CityCode,12),entrytime desc
```

and

```
Select * from news order by CityCode=12,entrytime desc
```

these codes did not work. I use mysql 5.5
how can i fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this : add `desc` in your order by clause for FIELD(CityCode,12)

```
Select * from news order by FIELD(CityCode,12) desc,entrytime desc
```

Check the limitations of FIELD function for ORDER BY

[Order BY using FIELD function](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-order-specific-field-values/)

Comment: thanks works great, i didnt add desc to order clause because i thought it will sort descending all citycodes :), but magicly it does not

Comment: check the link... it has good specification about FIELD function in order by clause

Answer (score 0):

Try following query:-

```
SELECT *
FROM NEWS
ORDER BY CASE WHEN CityCode=12 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END;
```

Here is the fiddle-

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f5dde/1