# With where in clause mysql query to select five specific row and another random row get limit 10

Tags: mysql, sql, eloquent

I want to display ten records.

> For eg

```
select * FROM users WHERE id (5,8,9,6,3) 
    UNION
SELECT * FROM users  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10
```

Now i want another row randomly selected from users table but with in ids and another random row get five.

Is it possible to do in a single query. I tried using union all but i dnt get 10 distinct rows.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySql Ordering by specific field value first does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25863919/mysql-ordering-by-specific-field-value-first-does-not-work)

Comment: Can you give us some example data and an example of your expected output? It's not entirely clear what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1):

This is working fine for me..

```
 SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY (user_id IN(5,8,9,6,3)) DESC, RAND() LIMIT 0,10
```

If Simply entering the condition will not work.So put a subquery. This is how the query looks.

```
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY (user_id = (select user_id FROM users WHERE 
the_condition)) DESC, RAND() LIMIT 0,10
```

Comment: Your first query answer is right. Do great Be continue best of luck thanks.